# Bing Map pushpin visualization (pushpin clipped) with AJAX SDK 7.0 AND HTML

Tags: bing-maps

I have 2 layer, in the first  layer i have a map and all works fine. The second  layer i have another map and i see the pushpin clipped. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN2Az.png
I have create the 2 maps with this code in 2 different var with 2 different target element

```
new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("idElementTarget"), {      credentials: mapKey, mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road, zoom: 13, enableClickableLogo: false, enableSearchLogo: false, disableBirdseye: true, showCopyright: false, showMapTypeSelector: false
});
```

There is a known bug on bings maps?

Answer (score 0):

Better Late than never and i hope you resolve this but the answer can help someone else,

I don't think that the bug come from Bing map but maybe your 2 Maps had the same z-index.

Referring to the picture, the right one just override the left one.